# Spring-mvc support

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm having troubles adding Spring-mvc support to a JSF based proyect.

Just added a controller:
...

```
@Controller("arestaController")
@RequestMapping(value="/ArestaController")
public class ArestaController {

    @Autowired
    private GenericBeanHelper beanHelper;
    @Autowired
    private GestioDocumentsArestaService gestioDocumentsArestaService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/getDocument",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void getDocument(@RequestBody String documentId,HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response){
```

....

And servlet configuration:

....

```
</listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>arestaController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>config servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>cat.gencat.tei.core.servlet.ConfigServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1000</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>arestaController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ArestaController/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

...

And I've Spring-context, Spring-web-mvc etc... at build path(and pom).

This is the console output starting server:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/EnvironmentAware
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2818)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1159)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1647)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
```

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 41 more
```

Thanks in advance,

David

P.D. Sorry for my english

Comment: Jsf and spring mvc are 2 different controller technologies, you cant use a spring controller to render a jsf view.

Comment: ... Yes, I know...